# How to show a specific row? Using SQLite + HTML5 + Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, sqlite

How to show a specific row?
In HTML + PHP I would do something like this:

```
<a href="show.php?id=5">See the ID #5</a>
```

And the show.php

```
<?php 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=$_GET[id]");
$row = mysql_fethc_assoc($query);
echo $row['name'];
?>
```

But how can I do this with only HTML + Sqlite?

Comment: You can't do this only with html & sqlite. You would need js and/or php too.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to solve the problem in this way.

```
<?php 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=$_GET[id]");
    $row = mysql_fethc_assoc($query);
    if($row['name']=="the name you want to find")
    {
    echo $row['name'];
    }
    ?>
```